# Draw multiple images at specific coordinates using Canvas and Bitmap

Tags: android, image, imageview, viewgroup, android-viewgroup

I am new to Android Development, I was learning canvas and bitmap and I wanted to draw a 5 pictures on 5 different coordinates on the screen. These coordinates are given by user and images are generated when a button is pressed. I was going through android documentation but that is giving me a hard struggle. Any suggestions on how should I proceed?
Thanks

Comment: Someone please suggest something , really struggling with this for a while now

Answer (score 0):

First, start by placing two textboxes and a button on the canvas, then when the button is clicked, pull the positions in the textbox and draw the pictures you have uploaded in the oncrate to the positions the user has entered, repeat this five times.